# Oracle same function run in different speed while invoked in different way

Tags: performance, oracle, function

Oracle 11g on Exadata. I have a function in a package. I test it in SQL developer.

When I invoke it use below SQL and 'run statement', it takes 90 seconds.

```
SELECT MSG_DESC
FROM TABLE (PKG_COMMON.FUNC_TEST(a,b,c,d));
```

When I invoke it use below SQL and 'run script, it takes less than 5 seconds.

```
declare
  V_MSG_DESC    VARCHAR(50);
BEGIN
  SELECT MSG_DESC
  INTO V_MSG_DESC
  FROM TABLE (PKG_COMMON.FUNC_TEST(a,b,c,d));
END;
```

I want to know what makes it so slow in the first way.

Comment: Did you run the SELECT statement first, and then run the PL/SQL block? If so, it may be that the SELECT loaded all the necessary data into Oracle's in-memory cache and the PL/SQL block then found all the data in the cache and didn't need to go to disk to read the data. Try running the queries above in reverse order and see what happens. Best of luck.

Comment: Are you able to post the function body? That does sounds very strange! Also if it only returns a single row then try select pkg_common.func_test(a,b,c,d) from dual; and see how long that takes

Comment: Sounds like Result Cache is kicking in. Like Bob Jarvis asked, how are you running this? One after another?, besure to flush the shared pool before benchmarking each one of them. Alter system flush shared_pool this will get rid of any entries in the Result Cache.